# Use of noImplicitAny in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-errors

I had read about the *noImplicitAny *in typescript documentation, but I still didn't get the idea the real use case of this item..

I had set it true false and comment the line there is a lot of confusion about this

case : 1

> "noImplicitAny": true

```
function addition(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
console.log(addition(2,3));

let demo;
```

In these line of code it shows error in the function parameter a and b as
*Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.*

question why its not shows any error in variable demo;

case : 2

> "noImplicitAny": false

```
function addition(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
console.log(addition(2,3));

let demo;
```

It don't show any kind of error

case 3

> // "noImplicitAny": true,   commented this line

```
function addition(a,b){
    return a+b;
}
console.log(addition(2,3));

let demo;
```

Its similar as case 1 showing error in function parameter as
*Parameter 'a' implicitly has an 'any' type.*
*Parameter 'b' implicitly has an 'any' type.*

why its not showing error in demo and whats the difference between case 1 and case 3?

I have done 3 methods but still don't get the clear Idea

Comment: `noImplicitAny` disallows variables that are implicitly declared as `any`. Case 1 and 3 are similar because `noImplicitAny: true` is the default. Have you read https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny

Comment: They differ because a variable behaves differently than a parameter variable. You can "change" the type of `demo` later when you assign to it, but you can't with a parameter variable: https://tsplay.dev/NDA46m